# Replace second occurence of ? with an &

Tags: c#, regex

Could anyone please provide the appropriate code to replace the second instance only of "?" in a string with a "&" ?

I've looked around but can't seem this done, and I'm not too hot with regex to begin with.

Thanks

Comment: just use IndexOf and on second occurrence, replace

Comment: If this is for querystring parsing, there's probably better ways.

Comment: What about the reverse way? Write only & and then replace the first one with ?

Comment: @RononDex - What if there are 3 or more `?` in the string?

Comment: I'm not parsing a query string. I have various string generation processes which I have to go through and can't edit them. They result in a second ? in the url.

Comment: Tell whoever wrote the processes to fix his code

Comment: Unfortunately I live in the real world.

Comment: I suppose string.Split() is an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `IndexOf` specifying the start index to find index of second question mark and then use `Substring`:

```
var index = input.IndexOf('?', input.IndexOf('?') + 1);
var ouput = string.Concat(input.Substring(0,index), "&", input.Substring(index + 1));
```

Or:

```
var output = new string(input.Select((c, i) => i == index ? '&' : c).ToArray());
```

You can also write an extension method:

```
public static string ReplaceWith(
        this string source, 
        char charToReplace,
        int index)
{
    if(source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    if (index == -1) return source;

    var output = new char[source.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i != index) output[i] = source[i];

        else output[i] = charToReplace;

    }
    return new string(output);
}
```

Then use it:

```
var index = input.IndexOf('?', input.IndexOf('?') + 1);
var output = input.ReplaceWith('&', index);
```

Comment: this output could be wrong (or an exception may be thrown) as there can sometimes be only one or no question marks

Comment: @LoganMurphy - Not per the OP's question, but definitely worth noting.

Comment: @LoganMurphy in the first solution, you'r right and that can be fixed a simple check  `if(index != -1)` but the second will just return the same string if there is no question mark, or one questions mark

Comment: @Selman22 this is how I'd probably do this practically, there's just not much need to using regexes for such a simple use case. +1

Answer (score 4):

The simplest `Regex` is probably:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(\?.*?)\?");
var test = "asdf?a=5?b=6&c=2";
test = regex.Replace(test, @"$1&"); // asdf?a=5&b=6&c=2

var test2 = "asdf?a=5?b=6?c=2";
test2 = regex.Replace(test, @"$1&"); // asdf?a=5&b=6?c=2
```

it will replace the second `?` with an `&`, but not the third/fourth/etc if they exist.

Answer (score 3):

replace:

```
(.*?\?.*?)(\?)(.*)
```

with `$1&$3` if you want to do it with a regex.

Comment: they want to replace ? with & so it might be `$1&$3`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it with this [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e47f3dkc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload.

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(^.*?\?.*?)(\?)");
var r = regex.Replace("asdf ? fdas ? jkl ?", m => m.Groups[1] + "&", 1).Dump();
// asdf ? fdas & jkl ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to an example below in which I remove the second and third occurrences of `$` from a given string.

```
string s = "like for example $  you don't have $  network $  access";       
Regex rgx = new Regex("\\$\\s+");
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\$\s+.*?)\$\s+", "$1$$");
```

Comment: How is this answering the question?