# How to replace a particular character from string in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have a string like `AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY`, I want to remove `X` from after the *first underscore* `_` i.e. from `1234X` to `1234`. So final output will be like `AX_1234_12345_X_CXY`. How to do it?? If I use `.Replace("X", "")` it will replace *all* `X` which I don't want

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace second occurence of ? with an &](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23547100/replace-second-occurence-of-with-an)

Comment: I think regex would be your answer in this.

Comment: What is the semantic meaning of `1234`?  What are you trying to accomplish, more generally?  Will it always be four digits followed by an `X`?  Extract a general pattern and then use regular expressions to search and replace.

Comment: wouldn't the final output be "AX_1234_12345__CXY" or am i missing something?

Comment: it can varry,only the condition is after the first underscore,so it can be AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY or AX_234X_12345_X_CXY

Comment: so only the second occurrence?

Comment: not the second ocuurence,but after the first underscore.It can even be AXXXX_1234X_12345_X_CXY

Comment: you're still not clear, all X's after the first "_" or only the second? Either way i think my method below could be tweaked.

Comment: all X's after the first "_"

Comment: so why in your expected output is the third X still there?

Comment: expected output is AXXXX_1234_12345_X_CXY if input is AXXXX_1234X_12345_X_CXY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate trough the string from the first occurrence of `'_'` .

 you can find the first occurrence of `'_'` using IndexOf().
when loop will get to 'X' it will not append it to the "fixed string".

```
private static void Func()
{
    string Original = "AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY";
    string Fixed = Original.Substring(0, Original.IndexOf("_", 0));
    // in case you want to remove all 'X`s' after first occurrence of `'_'` 
    // just dont use that variable
    bool found = false; 

    for (int i = Original.IndexOf("_", 0); i < Original.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Original[i].ToString()=="X" && found == false)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Fixed += Original[i];
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Fixed);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not good old `IndexOf` and `Substring`?

```
  string s = "AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY";

  int pUnder = s.IndexOf('_');

  if (pUnder >= 0) { // we have underscope...
    int pX = s.IndexOf('X', pUnder + 1); // we should search for X after the underscope

    if (pX >= 0) // ...as well as X after the underscope
      s = s.Substring(0, pX) + s.Substring(pX + 1);
  }

  Console.Write(s);
```

Outcome:

```
  AX_1234_12345_X_CXY
```

Comment: This is faster than my regex solution.  But if you want to make your solution twice as fast, do this instead: s = s.Remove(pX, 1); instead of your substrings.

Answer (score 1):

One way is String.Remove, because you can tell exactly where to remove from.  If the offending "X" is always in the same place, you can use:

```
string newString = old.Remove(7,1);
```

This will remove 1 character starting as position 7 (counting from zero as the beginning of the string).

If not always in the same character position, you might try:

```
int xPos = old.IndexOf("X");
string newString = old.Remove(xPos,1);
```

EDIT:

Based on OP comment, the "X" we're targeting occurs just **after** the first underscore character, so let's index off of the first underscore:

```
int iPosUnderscore = old.IndexOf("_");
string newString = old.Remove(iPosUnderscore + 1 ,1); // start after the underscore
```

Comment: 2nd suggestion won't work if there is an 'x' preceding the one you want in the string.

Comment: Agreed.  I based my answer on his exact question, which preserved the X characters occurring later in the input.

Comment: I'm just going to get nitpicky for a sec and mention that your variable name in the 2nd chunk of code is invalid.

Comment: @JLH it can varry,only the condition is after the first underscore,so it can be AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY or AX_234X_12345_X_CXY

Comment: @peter Understood, please see my edited example that takes that requirement into account.

Answer (score 1):

```
string original = @"AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY";

original = @"AX_1234_12345_X_CXY";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at `string.IndexOf` or `string.IndexOfAny`

```
string s = "AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY";
string ns = HappyChap(s);

public string HappyChap(string value)
{
        int start = value.IndexOf("X_");
        int next = start;

        next = value.IndexOf("X_", start + 1);
        if (next > 0)
        {
            value = value.Remove(next, 1);
        }

        return value;
}
```

Comment: loop not required if only 2nd occurrence

Comment: We don't really know the pattern here.  So how if we had "AX_1234C_12345_X_CXY", it would then give you a result of  "AX_1234C_12345__CXY"

Comment: we don't the question is lacking details. But I think the main concept used is IndexOf

Answer (score 0):

If and only if this is always the format then it should be a simple matter of combining substrings of the original text without including the x in that position. But the op hasn't stated that this is always the case. So if this is always the format and the same character position is always removed then you could simply just

```
    string s = "AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY";
    string newstring = s.Substring(0, 7) + s.Substring(8);
```

OK, based on only the second set of numbers being variable in length, you could then do something like:

```
int startpos = s.IndexOf('_', 4);
string newstring = s.Substring(0, startpos - 1) + s.Substring(startpos);
```

with this code, the following tests resulted in:

```
"AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY" became "AX_1234_12345_X_CXY"
"AX_123X_12345_X_CXY"  became "AX_123_12345_X_CXY"
"AX_234X_12345_X_CXY"  became "AX_234_12345_X_CXY"
"AX_1X_12345_X_CXY"    became "AX_1_12345_X_CXY"
```

Comment: it can varry,only the condition is after the first underscore,so it can be AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY or AX_234X_12345_X_CXY

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work.  I'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

```
 string input1 = "AX_1234X_12345_X_CXY";
 string pattern1 = "^[A-Z]{1,2}_[0-9]{1,4}(X)";
 string newInput = string.Empty;
 Match match = Regex.Match(input1, pattern1);
 if(match.Success){
    newInput =  input1.Remove(match.Groups[1].Index, 1);
 }            
 Console.WriteLine(newInput);
```